# reusing the result of service layer call in multiple controllers

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring application. Below is the scenario.
I have multiple controllers in a class as shown in the below code.I'm using the same service call in the two controllers.**Is there a way that the service call is made once and the result is used in multiple controllers**.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/details", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<String> detailData() throws Exception {
            List<MyDTO> results = myService.detailData();
            //business logic
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = "/detailsMontly", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public
        @ResponseBody List<String> montlyDetailData() throws Exception {
        List<MyDTO> results = myService.detailData();
        //business logic
    }
```

In the above code  `List<MyDTO> results = myService.detailData();` is called in two controllers, unnecessary two times i'm hitting the service layer which in turn hits database. Any advices?

Comment: How long do you need the data be preserved? What if a request comes today through one controller and then, after i.e. one day, another request comes through the other controller? Do you need to *always* return the cached value? Or is there some point in time when you will need to *refresh* what the controllers are returning?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at this chapter: [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

**TLDR;** you will need to:

1. mark a method of your service with `@Cacheable` annotation
2. ensure that application configuration is annotated with `@EnableCaching`
3. configure one of the available implementations of `CacheManager` bean

Answer (score 1):

There is only one call to the service method `myService.detailData()` in a given request context. Each of the two methods you have shown here maps to a different URL pattern. So there is only one call to your service in a given request context.

However, if `myService.detailData` retrieves static data from the database and hence is going to be common across requests, you can store it in a static variable. Do something like following:

```
private static List<MyDTO> results = null;

@ModelAttribute("results")
public List<MyDTO> getResults() {
    if (results == null) {
        results = myService.detailData;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: the service call myService.detailData should hit database and get the updated values whenever user requests using the requestMapping /details and /detailsMonlty. Will the code you mentioned satisfies that requirement.Do i need to create results property in my Model/DTO class?

Comment: @dexter, if the result set returned by this service is not always constant, you shouldn't use the code I have proposed. In that case, your original code is what you need. However, if the result set is something like list of states (which is constant for every request), you can use my solution.

Comment: @dexter, in that case, the statement `List<MyDTO> results = myService.detailData(); is called in two controllers, unnecessary two times` in your question is invalid. Firstly, this statement is not called twice in a given request. Secondly, even if it is called twice in the same request (maybe because of redirect), data retrieved can be different  like you say.